# Integral near the endpoints

Tags: calculus, integration

> Let $g:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be non-negative and integrable on $[a,b]$. 
>   If $\int_a^b g dx  > 0 $, then show that there exist $\epsilon > 0$ such that $\int_{a+\epsilon}^{b-\epsilon} g dx > 0$.

So I know that since $g \in \mathbb{R}[a,b]$, $g$ is bounded i.e. sup $|g| \le M$.
Then I have the feeling that somehow I must show:$$\int_{a+\epsilon}^{b-\epsilon} g dx  = \int_a^b g dx  - \int_{a}^{a+\epsilon} g dx  - \int_{b-\epsilon}^{b} g dx > 0$$

But I am stuck as to how to get the last inequality. I tried to link it with the sup near the endpoints but I can't really see the connection. Appreciate any help here, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose 
$$
\int_{a+\epsilon}^{b-\epsilon} g \mbox{ }dx = \int_a^b g\mbox{ } dx - \int_a^{a+\epsilon} g \mbox{ } dx - \int_{b-\epsilon}^b g \mbox{ } dx \leq 0
$$
for every $\epsilon > 0$ by way of contradiction. Rewriting gives
$$
\int_a^b g\mbox{ } dx \leq \int_a^{a+\epsilon} g \mbox{ } dx + \int_{b-\epsilon}^b g \mbox{ } dx \leq 2M \epsilon.
$$
for every $\epsilon > 0$, where $M > 0$ is so that $0 \leq g \leq M$ on $[a,b]$.
However, notice that this is absurd since we assumed the left hand integral in the above inequality to be positive. To be precise, there is an $N > 0$ so that
$$
0 < \frac{1}{N} < \int_a^b g\mbox{ } dx \leq 2M \epsilon
$$
but choosing $\epsilon = \frac{1}{4 N M}$ gives a contradiction. Therefore, there must some $\epsilon > 0$ so that the integral
$$
\int_{a+\epsilon}^{b-\epsilon} g \mbox{ }dx > 0.
$$

Comment: How do you get this inequality : $$\int_a^{a+\epsilon} g \mbox{ } dx + \int_{b-\epsilon}^b g \mbox{ } dx \leq 2M \epsilon.
$$?

Comment: Since $g \leq M$, we know that $\int_a^{a+\epsilon} g \mbox{ }dx \leq \int_a^{a+\epsilon} M \mbox{ } dx = M \int_a^{a+\epsilon} dx = M\big((a+\epsilon) - a\big) = M\epsilon$ and similarly for the other integral.

Comment: Ah I really feel stupid asking this question. Thank you so much for your explanation.

Comment: Hah. Don't feel stupid!! Sometimes we just don't see certain things right away. And no problem. Glad to help!

Comment: BTW, I noticed on your other questions that you did not accept answers for them either. It is generally a good gesture to do so if you found an answer helpful.